# Adding shadows to widgets in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I was trying to add a border shadow effect to a Container in a way that resembles exactly the same design as in the picture below. My initial idea was of using the CustomPaint class feature to do so. However, it hasn't worked out the way I wanted it to. I would honestly like to know how this can be achieved through the use of the `CustomPaint` class and I apologize for the code that I've written as I'm still trying to get used to `CustomPaint`. The code and the pictures are as follows:

This is what I intend to achieve:

[image]

This is what I have. You can see that the border goes well beyond where it should be and also, the border at the bottom gets clipped and despite adjusting the bottom padding:

[image]

This is the code:

```
class ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
        overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final textScale = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor * 1.2;

    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: height * 1,
            width: width * 1,
            // color: Colors.red,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/filter.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover)),
            child: Column(
              ......
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.035),
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: height * 0.25,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: width * 0.03,
                      top: height * 0.01,
                      // bottom: height * 0.01
                    ),
                    // color: Colors.yellow,
                    child: ProfilePageFavourite(),    //This here is the widget
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The ProfilePageFavourite widget:

```
class ProfilePageFavouriteState extends State<ProfilePageFavourite> {
  // final List<dynamic> _favouritesList = [

  // ];
  var favourite = false;

  void _onPressed() {
    setState(() => favourite = !favourite);
    print(favourite);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final textScale = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor * 1.2;

    // TODO: implement build
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Stack(
        children: [
          CustomPaint(                    //This is where I try using the CustomPaint class
            painter: OrangePainter(),
            child: Container(
              width: width * 0.75,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: width * 0.09),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/pub screen 1 (1).png'))),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: height * 0.16,
            child: Container(
              height: height * 0.07,
              width: width * 0.75,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: height * 0.008),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black38,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(20))),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.05),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              blurRadius: 35,
                              spreadRadius: 8,
                              offset: Offset(0, 2))
                        ]),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/icons/dine.png',
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: width * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Sollicitudin',
                        textScaleFactor: textScale,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            shadows: [
                              Shadow(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  blurRadius: 10,
                                  offset: Offset(0, 2))
                            ]),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      // color: Colors.red,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.118),
                      child: CustomRatingBar(4.5))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: width * 0.58,
            top: height * 0.01,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.pink,
                  blurRadius: 80,
                  spreadRadius: 6,
                )
              ]),
              child: !favourite
                  ? IconButton(
                      onPressed: _onPressed,
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.favorite,
                        // color: Color.fromRGBO(247, 180, 230, 0.8),
                        color: Colors.pink,
                        size: 50,
                      ))
                  : IconButton(
                      onPressed: _onPressed,
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
                        color: Colors.pink,
                        size: 50,
                      )),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      itemCount: 5,
    );
  }
}
```

The CustomPaint Class

```
class OrangePainter extends CustomPainter {
  OrangePainter();

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final rrectBorder =
        RRect.fromRectAndRadius(Offset.zero & size, Radius.circular(12));
    final rrectShadow =
        RRect.fromRectAndRadius(Offset(0, 2) & size, Radius.circular(12));

    final shadowPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.lightGreen
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 3
      ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.solid, 20);

    canvas.drawRRect(rrectShadow, shadowPaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest an alternative approach,  Custom Paint is very expensive to use in applications. You could instead wrap your container in a **Card()** then add your **shadowColor: Colors.lightGreen** set the **shape: ** to the same as your Container() and you should get the result you desire

Comment: Can you somehow suggest the solution to the above code?

Comment: Sure. However I will optimize your code because as it is, you are using a lot of widgets which can be cut down on. Reach me if you'll need further help with the implementation

Answer (score 0):

I have retained the initial customPaint and used it here.This code combines your ProfilePageState and ProfilePageFavourite to give you the appearance below. I've just built it on my phone's dartpad so you can do the editing so it matches. I included comments:
[image: UI]

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        height: 250,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: ListView.separated(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 5,
          separatorBuilder: (ctx, index) => const SizedBox(width: 10),
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => ClipRRect(
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: OrangePainter(),
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:10,vertical:15),//increase padding to your liking
                width: 350,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
//                 image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('')), add your image here and remove color below
                  color: Colors.black54,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: const [
                        Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 40),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        const Icon(Icons.restaurant),
                        const SizedBox(width:10),
                        Column(
                          children: const [
                            Text(
                              'Sollicitudin',
//                         textScaleFactor: textScale,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                shadows: [
                                  Shadow(
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                      blurRadius: 10,
                                      offset: Offset(0, 2))
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Icon(Icons.star),//Replace with your CustomRation()
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OrangePainter extends CustomPainter {
  OrangePainter();

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final rrectBorder =
        RRect.fromRectAndRadius(Offset.zero & size, const Radius.circular(12));
    final rrectShadow =
        RRect.fromRectAndRadius(const Offset(0, 2) & size, const Radius.circular(12));

    final shadowPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.lightGreen
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 3
      ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.solid, 20);

    canvas.drawRRect(rrectShadow, shadowPaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    return true;
  }
}
```